# Creating UIButton using helper method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit, uibutton

I have a subclass of `UITableView` and in it I want to generate number of labels that share the same properties (font, textColor, backgroundColor, etc.).

I decided the easiest way to achieve this would be to create a helper method which creates the label with some common properties set:

```
- (UILabel *)defaultLabelWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:128.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return label;
}
```

I use the method like this:

```
UILabel *someLabel = [self defaultLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
[self addSubview:someLabel];
[someLabel release];
```

My concern here is that **when creating the label in the method it is retained, but when I then assign it to someLabel, it is retained again and I have no way of releasing the memory when created in the method**.

**What would be best the best approach here?**

I fee like I have two options:

1. Create a subclass of UILabel for the default label type.
2. Create an NSMutableArray called **defaultLabels** and store the labels in this:

```
- (UILabel *)defaultLabelWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:128.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [defaultLabels addObject:label];
    [labels release]; //I can release here
    return [defaultLabels lastObject]; //I can release defaultLabels when done
}
```

I appreciate your thoughts. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to autorelease your object before you return it:

```
- (UILabel *)defaultLabelWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   …
   return [label autorelease];
}
```

Most methods in Cocoa will retain objects as needed, including `addSubview:`. If no object uses (i.e. retains) the label, you don’t need to worry about it being leaked — it’s already been added to the autorelease pool and will be released automatically.

Comment: So in terms of using the label, UILabel *label = [self defaultLabelWithFrame:CGRectZero]; ... [label release]; I don't have to worry about releasing label then?

Comment: Right. You won’t have to release the label manually. The view that retained it will release it. In fact, you could simply use `[self addSubview:[self defaultLabelWithFrame:…]]`.

Comment: Thanks. I have one case where i'm using self.label = [self default...] and then setting self.label = nil in dealloc. This way I can retain the label for as long as I need it. That won't cause any problems?

Comment: No: your object will retain it, giving it a +2 retain count. Then, the autorelease will run, giving it a +1 retain count. Then, when you set it to nil, your object wil release it as well, putting it to 0 (and deallocating it). Please read the Apple documentation on the topic, it's very clear and you won't ever have another issue with memory management.